# RxSwift UIPicker crashes when setting delegate

Tags: swift, rx-swift

so I set up a uipicker for my app, the code is as follows

```
self.leftPicker.rx.setDelegate(self).disposed(by: bag)
        Driver.just([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
            .drive(leftPicker.rx.items){
                index, item, view in
                if let label = view as? UILabel{
                    return label
                }
                let label = UILabel()
                label.font = UIFont(name: SRFonts.asap_regular.fontName, size: 13)
                label.textAlignment = .center
                label.text = "\(item)"
                return label
        }
        .disposed(by: bag)
```

if I do this, the app will crash, saying that there is a conflicting delegate... so if I am to remove

```
self.leftPicker.rx.setDelegate(self).disposed(by: bag)
```

the crash is gone...

But the problem is that, I wish to set the height for the uipicker rows, without the delegate, I can't seem to set height in

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 44
    }
```

This is really weird, cuz it usually works for RxTableView and RxCollectionView.

Anyone knows what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What immediately caught my attention is that you are passing an array instead of array of arrays. Try **[[1,2,3,4,5,6]]** instead.

```swift
let data: PickerViewAdapter.Element = [
        ["0", "1", "2"],
        ["a", "b", "c"]
    ]

Observable.just(data)
  .bind(to: pickerView.rx.items(adapter: PickerViewAdapter()))
  .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)

final class PickerViewAdapter: NSObject
    , UIPickerViewDataSource
    , UIPickerViewDelegate
    , RxPickerViewDataSourceType
    , SectionedViewDataSourceType {

    typealias Element = [[CustomStringConvertible]]
    private var items: [[CustomStringConvertible]] = []

    func model(at indexPath: IndexPath) throws -> Any {
        return items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return items[component].count
    }

    /* ... */
```

**EDIT:**

Also, In my example, Adapter is the delegate. If you don't specify one, it will create delegate automatically (see https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxCocoa/iOS/UIPickerView%2BRx.swift), hence the conflict.

Try *.bind(to: pickerView.rx.items(adapter: PickerViewAdapter()))* with your custom adapter class.

Comment: uhmm, passing array is perfectly fine.. it is just tableview with only one section.. What you are doing here is assuming you have multiple components... Anyway, it doesnt answer the question at all.

Comment: In my example, Adapter is the delegate. If you don't specify one, it will create delegate automatically (see https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxCocoa/iOS/UIPickerView%2BRx.swift), hence the conflict. Try *.bind(to: pickerView.rx.items(adapter: PickerViewAdapter()))* with your custom adapter class.